# How do I fix this error I'm getting when I try to install this package with pip install?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I've been trying to start a Discord bot on my computer, but whenever I try to install sudo pip install discord.py I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-QOFKFs/aiohttp/setup.py", line 60, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+")
RuntimeError: aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+
```

I'm running Linux Mint 18.2 and I'm almost 100% positive I've got Python and Pip up to date.

Comment: maybe you are using python 2. Let's try `sudo pip3 install discord.py`

Comment: try `sudo -H pip3 install discord.py`

Answer (score -1):

Have you check pip is really pip for python3 and python's version?
You could using pip for python2.
Like this [link](https://www.oschina.net/question/2690200_2177519)